# Use a controller in another controller in Angular

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui, angular-ui-bootstrap

The [modal in angular-ui](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/modal) example is implemented with a `ModalInstanceCtrl` inside a `ModalDemoCtrl` controller like so:

```
var ModalDemoCtrl = function ($scope, $modal, $log) {
  $scope.open = function () {

    var modalInstance = $modal.open({
      ...
      controller: ModalInstanceCtrl,
     ...
    });
    ...
  };
};

var ModalInstanceCtrl = function ($scope, $modalInstance, items) {
  ...

  $scope.ok = function () {
    $modalInstance.close($scope.selected.item);
  };
};
```

When trying this approach by registering the Controllers with angular like so:

```
app.controller('ModalInstanceCtrl', ['$scope', '$modal', '$log',
 function ($scope, $modalInstance, items) {
  ...

  $scope.ok = function () {
    $modalInstance.close($scope.selected.item);
  };
}]);

app.controller('ModalDemoCtrl', ['$scope', '$modal', '$log', 'ModalInstanceCtrl',
 function ($scope, $modal, $log, ModalInstanceCtrl) {
  $scope.open = function () {

    var modalInstance = $modal.open({
      ...
      controller: ModalInstanceCtrl,
     ...
    });
    ...
  };
 }]);
```

I get the following error:

```
Error: Unknown provider: ModalInstanceCtrlProvider <- ModalInstanceCtrl
```

Should it be possible to nest controllers like this in angular?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need to inject `ModelInstanceCtrl` into your `ModalDemoCtrl`. The controller definition should be

```
app.controller('ModalDemoCtrl', ['$scope', '$modal', '$log',
 function ($scope, $modal, $log) {
```

It should work without this too. If it does not try

```
 var modalInstance = $modal.open({
      ...
      controller: 'ModalInstanceCtrl',
     ...
    });
```